# add custom css to <i> tag inside <a> tag in wordpress navigation

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I have this code:

```
 <li>
   <a href="#">
     <i class="icon-student"></i>menu1
   </a>
 </li>
 <li>
   <a href="#">
     <i class="icon-book"></i>menu1
   </a>
 </li>
 <li>
   <a href="#">
     <i class="icon-shop"></i>menu1
   </a>
</li>
```

I want to add automatically custom css (by user) into `<i>` tag not `<li>` tag.
How I can do that?

Comment: Rephrase the question please, it is not clear what you need

Comment: Would you please refer this article http://sevenspark.com/how-to/how-to-add-a-custom-class-to-a-wordpress-menu-item ? It's might be helpful for you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? . Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question. If you want to insert any content before tag "i", you can use the selector ":before" . You can add some content like text or images for example.

Between "i" and "a" you can't use any custom css because you don't have elements between.

To access directly to i, you can using in your CSS: li a i {

Hope I help you.

Comment: Don't answer a question if it is not clear what they are asking, ask for further clarification in the comments.  As you don't have enough rep to comment yet, you need to build up your rep to comment - you are most likely not going to do it by answering these types of question

Comment: @Pete Thanks for the advice

Comment: In Wordpress panel you can add custom Css to each menu item. Wordpress by default add this css to <li> tag like this: <li class="your-class">menu name </li>. But I want to add this class to another tag like <i> or <span> before or after menu name linke this: <li><a>menu name<i class="your-class"><i></a></li>.